# Время жизни в Rust. Семантика и принцип работы

Tags: rust, время-жизни

Помогите разобраться с таким вопросом:

Делаю две структуры, одна `FullJson`, вторая `BodyJson`. `FullJson` включает `BodyJson`, как одно из своих полей. А затем в функции `loop` создается 10 экземпляров `FullJson` и передается куда-то дальше.

При компиляции вылезла ошибка `expected lifetime parameter...`

Полез смотреть про время жизни в Rust, понатыкал `<'a>`, `<'b>`, вроде ошибка исчезла. Но я стараюсь понять принцип работы этой штуки...

Ниже будет код, который в итоге получился.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что создав `BodyJson<'a>` и `FullJson<'b>` я обозначил их времени жизни и что у `BodyJson<'b>` стало время жизни `FullJson`? И такой вопрос - почему компилятор затребовал, чтобы я сделал вот так: `body: &'b BodyJson<'b>`, т.е. указал два раза `'b`?

Ссылка на gist: https://gist.github.com/rogerwilcos/70a78af82713779f1574d030f6013c52

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_json;
extern crate exonum;

use exonum::crypto::{self, CryptoHash, Hash, PublicKey, SecretKey};

#[derive(Serialize, Debug)]
struct BodyJson<'a> {
    pub_key: &'a PublicKey,
    act_id: &'a str,
    form_act_id: &'a str,
    block: &'a str,
    status: &'a str,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Debug)]
struct FullJson<'b> {
    network_id: &'b str,
    protocol_version: &'b str,
    service_id: &'b str,
    message_id: &'b str,
    signature: exonum::crypto::SecretKey,
    body: &'b BodyJson<'b>,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В rust у всех ссылок имеется время жизни. В простых случаях, например при использовании локальных переменных - ссылок, их время жизни может выводится из контекста. Однако в более сложных сценариях время жизни ссылок необходимо указывать явно. В вашем случае каждая из структур содержит множество ссылок и для всех них необходимо явно указывать время жизни. При объявлении каждой структуры можно задать псевдо параметры с именем, начинающимся с `'`, которые обозначают время жизни. Указывая параметр времени жизни для ссылочных полей структуры `act_id: &'a str` вы явно задаете время жизни каждой ссылки. При создании ссылки на `BodyJson` параметр времени жизни указывается два раза, так как первый параметр `&'b` относится к самой ссылке, а второй параметр задает параметр времени жизни `'a` для полей внутри структуре `BodyJson`.